# Errors when trying to bring ethernet interface up on embedded Linux

Tags: kernel, embedded, ethernet, ifconfig, ioctl

I am trying to compile the Linux kernel (3.0.8, buildroot-gcc-12.3.0, ARMv7) to run on my IP camera.
**eth0** is not able to get up.
At first, kernel boot just crashed at *Starting network* step:

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00006e78...
```

I've removed some network related lines from **init** to be able to get a little further.

Now any manual attepmt to address **eth0** using **ifconfig** or **ip** gives either similar kernel paging error, or this one:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such device or address
```

Below is one of **strace** runs I've tried:

```
root@openipc-fh8856v100:/tmp# strace -i ifconfig eth0 up
[4024ff14] execve("/sbin/ifconfig", ["ifconfig", "eth0", "up"], 0xbee90e3c /* 13 vars */) = 0
[40206f14] set_tls(0x4025b4cc)          = 0
[401cfbd0] set_tid_address(0x4025a7cc)  = 596
[401dbf24] brk(NULL)                    = 0x4015e000
[401dbf44] brk(0x40160000)              = 0x40160000
[401e4c50] mmap2(0x4015e000, 4096, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4015e000
[401e4cac] mprotect(0x4015b000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
[402106c8] getuid32()                   = 0
[401eceac] socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
[401e2a58] ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_flags=IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
[401e2a58] ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
[40207148] write(2, "ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such "..., 50ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such device or address
) = 50
[401d04fc] exit_group(1)                = ?
[????????] +++ exited with 1 +++enter code here
```

Logs show the **fh_gmac** driver loaded fine during the boot, but later eth0 could not be started:

```
root@openipc-fh8856v100:/tmp# dmesg | grep -i eth
[    1.395036] fh_gmac fh_gmac.0: eth0: mixed HW and IP checksum settings.
[    1.400892] fh_gmac fh_gmac.0: eth0: mixed no checksumming and other settings.
[    1.408363]  eth0 - (dev. name: fh_gmac - id: 0, IRQ #15
[  130.106506] eth0: MII BUS or phydev is NULL
[  308.876503] eth0: MII BUS or phydev is NULL
```

**interfaces** file looks fine to me:

```
root@openipc-fh8856v100:/etc/network# cat interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 169.254.38.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 169.254.38.163
dns-nameservers 169.254.38.163 8.8.8.8
```

The ethernet is working fine on this cam in the original firmware with almost identical settings.

Any advice is appreciated.